# How to read HAR file posted by Selenium Automated Performance Test?

Tags: selenium, firebug, har

I've used [this](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firebug/automate-page-load-performance-testing-with-firebug-and-selenium/) reference for doing Automated Page Load Performance test in Selenium using Firefox, Firebug and NetExport (A Firebug extension). My final aim is just to extract the page load time from the HAR file. The HAR file gets generated and is stored on the local disk. That works perfectly.

There is a second approach described in the reference I've linked above having a header "Send HAR files to Server". I followed the steps described but not sure about where to save the PHP script shown later. I tried to keep it in `http://localhost/har-db` and gave the PHP file some name viz. `getHARData.php` but don't know what to write in the JAVA program so that it will access that file. The file desires to receive a `REQUEST` parameter but not sure how to make it access the URL it wants as a `REQUEST` variable. All the code is available on the linked site. I've not done any improvisations except changing the paths of `.xpi` files of the Firefox extensions.

Any optimized workarounds are most welcome.

Comment: You have the HAR file, so what do you/author-of-blog means by "Send HAR files to Server"?

Comment: @amey That is one approach of getting HAR file you are talking about. I want to send the file directly to the server and don't want to export it on local disk so that the PHP file can access as a REQUEST parameter as described in the program.